# tcl data formats confusion

Tags: foreach, split, tcl

The motivation behind this question is learning...

I have done some TCL programming and I do have a working code, but I do not understand why some syntax is working and another not.

**Problem description:**
I'm writing a code that needs to set the voltages for power and ground nets. 
After I enter the VDD nets as a string,

```
set POWER_NETS "vdd=1.1 vdda=1.2 vref=1.1"
```

then a simple TCL code should construct and execute the following commands:

```
set_vdd vdd 1.1
set_vdd vdda 1.2
set_vdd vref 1.1
```

That is all. It seems trivial, but I have had some difficulty implementing it. I still do not understand why sometimes my code does not work, although it seems correct to me.

**Working solution:** The only working solution that I came up with is following:

```
foreach ITEM [split $POWER_NETS] {
    set NET [lindex [split $ITEM =] 0]
    set VOLTAGE [lindex [split $ITEM =] 1]
    set_vdd $NET $VOLTAGE
}
```

That's a lot of code for such a simple operation. When written in a more condensed form it still works:

```
foreach ITEM [split $POWER_NETS] {
    set_vdd [lindex [split $ITEM =] 0] [lindex [split $ITEM =] 1]
}
```

But I still have a feeling that there is room for improvement here.

**Learning objective:** I would like to settle with this solution as optimal code (it is both short and comprehensive)

```
foreach ITEM [split $POWER_NETS] {
    set_vdd [split $ITEM =]
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. The tool that interprets the set_vdd command complains that

```
no value given for parameter "voltage" (use -help for full usage) :
```

**I do not understand why this does not work. What is the difference?**

When I replace `set_vdd` with `puts`, it does print all the values. So all information is there. Isn't it?

```
nlv12345@acc3081 CHAR_OUT_LOGS $ tclsh
% set POWER_NETS "vdd=1.1 vdda=1.2 vref=1.1"
vdd=1.1 vdda=1.2 vref=1.1
% foreach ITEM [split $POWER_NETS] {
    puts [split $ITEM =]
}
vdd 1.1
vdda 1.2
vref 1.1
%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is less than optimal, but the problem is that you're passing the two words out of `split` as a *single argument* to `set_vdd`.

If your Tcl interpreter is any currently-supported version, you can instead do this:

```
foreach ITEM [split $POWER_NETS] {
    set_vdd {*}[split $ITEM =]
}
```

The `{*}` is a marker to say “take this list — the rest of this word — and split it into separate arguments”. While it's formally not an operator but rather a syntactic part of the Tcl language, calling it the “expansion operator” won't confuse you a lot.

---

Older, unsupported versions of Tcl (8.4 and before) require the use of `eval` to do this. You're probably OK with:

```
foreach ITEM [split $POWER_NETS] {
    eval set_vdd [split $ITEM =]
}
```

but really it would be safer to do this:

```
foreach ITEM [split $POWER_NETS] {
    eval [linsert [split $ITEM =] 0 set_vdd]
}
```

As you can see, the `{*}` simplifies things quite a bit.

---

However, I'd actually do this:

```
foreach {ITEM KEY VALUE} [regexp -all -inline {(\w+)=([\d.]+)} $POWER_NETS] {
    set_vdd $KEY $VALUE
}
```

Like that, unexpected things in the `POWER_NETS` value won't cause so much trouble. OTOH, if you're not used to regular expressions then perhaps now is not the time to start with `regexp`…

Comment: Thanks, all of them work. Of course, I have implemented the shortest one `{*}`. :) Not that I'm unfamiliar with regexp, but it is not important to make a fool-proof solution. The users should have some discipline not to mess-up the input variables.

Answer (score 2):

Two other simple solutions, for inspiration and further learning:

```
set POWER_NETS "vdd=1.1 vdda=1.2 vref=1.1"
foreach ITEM [split $POWER_NETS] {
    lassign [split $ITEM =] NET VOLTAGE
    set_vdd $NET $VOLTAGE
}
```

This one uses `lassign` to assign the parts of `ITEM` instead of splitting them into nameless parameters.

```
set POWER_NETS [string map {= { }} "vdd=1.1 vdda=1.2 vref=1.1"]
foreach {NET VOLTAGE} [split $POWER_NETS] {
    set_vdd $NET $VOLTAGE
}
```

This one replaces the equals signs with spaces and then lets `foreach` extract the two values pairwise.

Documentation:
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)